# Como enviar datos de un JDialog a un JInternalFrame ya abierto

Tags: java

tengo un problema que no logro solucionar por falta de entendimiento.
El lenguaje de programacion es Java.

Tengo un JInternalFrame abierto donde tengo una seria de campos, de lo cuales hay un botón que abre un JDialog, en el mismo se encuentran los datos de todos los proveedores que tengo, el problema surge que al momento de abrir el jdialog necesito que desde la tabla donde muestra los datos de los proveedores al momento de darle click sobre la tabla y apretar el botón para que envié los datos al JInternalFrame que contiene un JComboBox que es donde quiero mostrar el proveedor seleccionado no lo recibe.
He probado pasandole al contructor del JInternalFrame el proveedor por parametro pero tampoco lo recibe.
Dejo algo de codigo de los botones que utilizo y el constructor como se inicializa.

//Evento del Jdialog que envia el proveedor hasta el comboBox de JInternalFrame.

```
    private void  seleccionarProveedorActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
    Proveedor proveedor = (Proveedor)modeloTabla.getValueAt(tablaProveedores.getSelectedRow(),1);

    inventario = new VistaINVENTARIO(proveedor);
        
    inventario.comboBoxProveedores.setSelectedIndex(proveedor.getIdProveedor());        

}
```

//EVENTO DEL JInternalFrame que abre el Jdialog

```
    private void abrirVentanaProveedoresActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    try {

        JDialog Proveedor =Singleton.getVistaPROVEEDORES();
        Proveedor.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Proveedor.setVisible(true);
        

    } catch (Exception f) {
        f.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

gracias por tu respuesta.

Te comento, en la linea que dices que esta mal y que debería devolver una cast Exception, eso esta correcto ya que almaceno en la tabla sobre la columna 1 el proveedor completo, no obtengo los datos desde la tabla en si, sino de la base de datos.

por otro lado cambie de DefaultTableModel a AbstractTableModel como habías mencionado creo que esta muy bien esta implementación pero me surge un problema donde yo tenia creado un buscador, pero no logro implementarlo con AbstractTableModel, Comparto la clase que tenia antes y la que acabo de crear y si puedes guiarme  como debería ser el nuevo método con el buscador utilizando el la nueva clase "AbstractTableModel". Una vez terminado esto, podría seguir con el problema en cuestión.

//NUEVA CLASE CREADA

```
public class ModeloTablaProveedores extends AbstractTableModel {
private BaseDatos base=new BaseDatos();
private ArrayList<Proveedor> proveedores = base.dameProveedoresTabla();
private String[] columnas = { "id", "descripción", "dirección", "correo", "telefono" };
private String[] cproveedores = { "id", "descripción" };
private int tipoVista;
private final static int COMPLETO = 1;
private final static int SIMPLE = 2;
@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return proveedores.size();
}

@Override // DEVUELVE EL NOMBRE DE LA COLUMNA
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return columnas[column];
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnas.length;
}

public Proveedor getFila(int indice) {
    return proveedores.get(indice);
}

public ModeloTablaProveedores() {
    this.tipoVista = COMPLETO;

}


public void limpiar() {
    int ur = proveedores.size();
    proveedores.clear();
    this.fireTableRowsDeleted(0, ur);
}



@Override // CARGA LOS DATOS EN LA TABLA
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return proveedores.get(rowIndex).getIdProveedor();
        case 1:
            return proveedores.get(rowIndex).getNomProveedor();
        case 2:
            return proveedores.get(rowIndex).getDirProveedor();
        case 3:
            return proveedores.get(rowIndex).getMailProveedor();
        case 4:
            return proveedores.get(rowIndex).getTelProveedor();
        default:
            return null;
        }

    

}

}
```

//Metodo anterior que busca por criterio.

```
private void txtDescKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt{//GEN-FIRST:event_txtDescKeyReleased
                
            LimpiarLista();
    
            String cadena = txtDesc.getText();
            
            ArrayList<Proveedor> listaProveedor = base.obtenerProveedoresPorCriterio(cadena);

            int numeroProducto = listaProveedor.size();
            modeloTabla.setNumRows(numeroProducto);
            for (int i = 0; i < numeroProducto; i++) {

                Proveedor proveedor = listaProveedor.get(i);
                int clave = proveedor.getIdProveedor();
                String nomBre = proveedor.getNomProveedor();
                String dir = proveedor.getDirProveedor();
                String tel = proveedor.getTelProveedor();
                String mail = proveedor.getMailProveedor();

                modeloTabla.setValueAt(clave, i, 0);
                modeloTabla.setValueAt(proveedor, i, 1);
                modeloTabla.setValueAt(dir, i, 2);
                modeloTabla.setValueAt(tel, i, 3);
                modeloTabla.setValueAt(mail, i, 4);

   
   }
}
```

Intente a este metodo usarlo con el AbstracTableModel pero no logro que funcione, me falta el metodo setNumRows, pero al tener el setValuAt sobreescrito no se como deberia hacerlo en la nueva clase, me gustaria que solo llame a la clase de la siguiente manera

```
private void txtDescKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

modeloTablaProveedores.limpiar();
    
String cadena = txtDesc.getText();

modeloTablaProveedores.buscarProveedores(criterio);

}
```

Donde modeloTablaProveedores es una instancia de ModeloTablaProveedores.

Comment: Primero tienes que decidir si el diálogo regresará únicamente el id del proveedor o todo el objeto. Considera que si a partir del diálogo creas/modificas/eliminas un proveedor, la lista del combo box debe actualizarse, y seguramente los ids de proveedor no corresponderán a los índices ni del combo box ni del número de renglón seleccionado.

Comment: Hola @Sal el JDialog de proveedores es un ABM donde se va abrir desde la parte de articulos. El comboBox quiero editarlo para que solo resiva int que son el id, al momento de que se envia la informacion al lado del id mostrar un JLabel con el nombre del proveedor. Ese modelo quiero cambiarlo porque esta creado con objetos de tipo proveedor.

Answer (score 0):

Esta instrucción está mal:
`Proveedor proveedor = (Proveedor)modeloTabla.getValueAt(tablaProveedores.getSelectedRow(),1);`
Esto debería botarte una class cast exception. No sé si estás usando un default table model o una especialización de AbstractTableModel; pero si es la primera opción, tendrías que extraer el dato desde el data vector: `(Proveedor)modeloTabla.getDataVector().get(tablaProveedores.getSelectedRow());`

Ahora, como verás, el DefaultTableModel no usa type erarsure, y encima se respalda en un Vector, que ya a estas alturas está en desuso y se considera obsoleto. Yo te aconsejaría que mejor uses tu propia especialización de AbstractTableModel respaldada sobre un ArrayList, que es más eficiente y mejor diseñado que Vector, además así puedes tener type erasure (o Proveedor directamente) sin necesidad de estar haciendo el cast en tu código.

Por otro lado, si tu JTable de proveedores se puede ordenar, entonces necesitarás convertir el selectedIndex de la vista al modelo:
`modeloTabla.getDataVector().get(tablaProveedores.convertRowIndexToModel(tablaProveedores.getSelectedRow());`

También, te recomendaría que primero valides el user input, porque, ¿qué pasaría si tu usuario no selecciona nada? Entonces, `tablaProveedores.getSelectedRow()` retornaría -1, y eso causaría un `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, y aunque en teoría lo tienes cubierto en tu try...catch, es más amigable que si el usuario no selecciona nada, simplemente no haga nada, o le dé un mensaje que diga "Oye wei, te olvidaste de seleccionar un proveedor", en lugar de un mensaje de error genérico.

Comment: Gracias @bichoFlyer por tu comentario, me ayudo lo de la validación, pero con el código que compartió Sal pude resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Lo normal sería que el marco interno cache cuando se cierra el diálogo.
Pero la implementación de JOptionPane interesantemente evita la dependencia mediante un método estático que se encarga de abrir el diálogo, contener eventos externos hasta que se cierre el diálogo para finalmente regresar la opción seleccionada.

```
private void  seleccionarProveedorActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    this.setVisible(false);
}

public Integer getSeleccion(){
    return modeloTabla.getValueAt(tablaProveedores.getSelectedRow(),1);
}
```

```
private void abrirVentanaProveedoresActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    try {

        JDialog proveedor =Singleton.getVistaPROVEEDORES();
        proveedor.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        proveedor.setVisible(true);

        // Bloquear eventos hasta que se cierre el diálogo
        while( proveedor.isShowing() ){
            if( EventQueue.isDispatchThread() ){
                AWTEvent ev = eq.getNextEvent();
                if( ev instanceof ActiveEvent )
                    ((ActiveEvent)ev).dispatch();
                else if( ev.getSource() instanceof Component )
                    ((Component)ev.getSource()).dispatchEvent(ev);
            }else
                Thread.yield();
        }

        System.out.println( "Proveedor seleccionado "+proveedor.getSeleccion() );
        // ¿Los ids y los índices corresponden?
        comboBoxProveedores.setSelectedIndex(proveedor.getSeleccion()); 
        
    } catch( InterruptedException ie ) {

    } catch (Exception f) {
        f.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: muy cordial de tu parte tu explicación y tu código. Tratare de analizarlo e intentar implementarlo, escribiré por este medio posibles dudas, Gracias.

Comment: Por medio de tu codigo he podido realizar lo que estaba necesitando, tendre que indagar mas en este codigo ya que esta implementado de tal manera que me cuesta entenderlo, lo adapte tal cual lo hiciste y ha sido correcto. 

Gracias por tu ayudar. @Sal